# how to find angle braket literals with grep

Tags: regex, grep

In the following example, the second match "<_dl_start_user>" was unexpected:

```
$  objdump -D /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2|grep -A5 '<_start>:'
0000003ba0400b30 <_start>:
  3ba0400b30:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  3ba0400b33:   e8 28 06 00 00          callq  3ba0401160 <_dl_start>

0000003ba0400b38 <_dl_start_user>:
  3ba0400b38:   49 89 c4                mov    %rax,%r12
```

how can I match exactly '<_start>:' ?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how is it working differently from your expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching `<_start>:` exactly. You're also seeing 5 lines of trailing context after the match because you specified `-A5`.